# @TargetApi(19) and CaptioningManager

Tags: android

I'm working on a application where I use the API 19 and the feature Closed Caption, but not all my devices have Kit kat installed, for this reason when I use something of this API I put that:

```
@TargetApi(19)
private Boolean getStateAndroidCC()
{
    CaptioningManager captioningManager = (CaptioningManager) context.getSystemService(
                        Context.CAPTIONING_SERVICE);

    return captioningManager.isEnabled();
}
```

But When I run the application and check the console of Logcat, I see this line:

****Could not find class 'android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager'**

Can you help me to resolve that ?

Because I read that if I use this tag @TargetApi(19),this problem will be resolved, but I can not fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`@TargetApi` annotation is used to supress the Lint API check, so you wouldn't have a compile error.

It means: I'm aware that I'm calling an API which might not be available on all devices **and** I am properly handling it.

So you have to check if you're running Kitkat before you call the API in question:

```
@TargetApi(19)
private Boolean getStateAndroidCC()
{
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
         CaptioningManager captioningManager = (CaptioningManager) context.getSystemService(
                    Context.CAPTIONING_SERVICE);

         return captioningManager.isEnabled();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yeap !! I think the same about the @TargetApi. Thanks for your response. I will do that and then I tell you  the results :)